# "Open in browser" Docker container sends me to the getting-started tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, docker, postman, fastapi

I'm currently following this fastAPI guide [fastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/) and the first time I completed the guide it worked and I was using Postman to look at some simple GET requests.

I'm not sure what I did wrong but I recreated everything from the tutorial but with different image names and container names and now every time I click on "OPEN IN BROWSER" from the Docker dashboard, it sends me to the main tutorial of "Getting Started" with Docker.
I tried killing all localhosts and starting over but every time I type `localhost:80` it sends me to the tutorial but when I type `http://127.0.0.1/docs` in the URL it sends me to the fastAPI openapi.json and I can test the GET requests with no issues.

Why is `localhost:80` constantly sending me to the Docker startup tutorial?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:80/docs` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Getting-Started Docker container was also on port 80 and even though it wasn't running; it still would send me to the getting-started page. I fixed this by changing the port to port 90 on my new Docker container and that fixed it.